# Could anyone please explain me this function, I am not able to understand this

Tags: c++, c, arduino

```
   unsigned long fileSize = file.size();
   byte buf[4];
   buf[0] = (byte) fileSize & 0xFF;
   buf[1] = (byte) (fileSize >> 8) & 0xFF;
   buf[2] = (byte) (fileSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
   buf[3] = (byte) (fileSize >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

can anyone explain me this code.assuming a file with a size of your choice

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with bitshifting? With bitwise operations? With casting? Please be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you wanted to split a decimal number 8375 into digits. You could do it this way:

```
unsigned     value = 8375;
unsigned     digit_0 =  value         % 10;  // Gives 5
unsigned     digit_1 = (value /   10) % 10;  // Gives 7
unsigned     digit_2 = (value /  100) % 10;  // Gives 3
unsigned     digit_3 = (value / 1000) % 10;  // Gives 8
```

Well, the code you posted does just that. Only it splits the number into *octets* which are *pairs of hexadecimal* digits. I.e. every octet can take values in the range [0..255].

And the posted code uses bitwise operations:
`(a >> 8)` is actually `(a / 256)`, and `(a & 0xFF)` is `(a % 256)`.

Comment: Illustrative code would have been closer using `unsigned`.  With `int`, `a >> 8` is not the same as `a/256` and `a & 0xFF` is not `a%256` when `a < 0`.

Answer (score 3):

The code is taking the lower 4 bytes of the file size (`unsigned long` may be 4 or 8 bytes, depending on platform/compiler), and is storing those 4 individual bytes into the `buf` array in [little-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

It takes the lowest 8 bits of `fileSize` and stores them into `buf[0]`, then takes the next-lowest 8 bits and stores them into `buf[1]`, and so on for `buf[2]` and `buf[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

The program is storing the four bytes of an unsigned long integer into another byte array. The statement `buf[0] = (byte) fileSize & 0xFF;` performs a bit-masking and hence the last 8 bits are extracted from the unsigned long number. To extract further 8 bits, we shift the number right 8 bits and then again perform the bit-masking and so on.

Comment: sir how to know how many times to perform that statement

Comment: We can use the expression `sizeof(unsigned long)` to determine the number of bytes used by the `unsigned long`.


byte buf[sizeof(unsigned long)];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned long); i++) {

    buf[i] = (byte) (filesize >> (8 * i)) & 0xff;
}



Note that the above code assumes that a `byte` consists of 8 bits. If we want to make that also generic, we can use `CHAR_BIT` and \UCHAR_MAX` from `clmiits`.

The `CHAR_BIT` defines the number of bits that goes in a `char` type and `UCHAR_MAX` gives the maximum value of an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply finding the 4 bytes of a 4-byte integer. It's doing in hex what you'd do to find [2,0,2,0] from 2020.

The way it does it is by shifting the bits and using AND with a mask of all 1s.

Comment: /s 4 *bits* of a 4-byte integer?

Comment: Well you specify the number of bits with the >> operator, but the memory is addressed in bytes

Answer (score -1):

on little endian system it the same as:

```
memcpy(buf, &fileSize, 4);
```

or

```
union 
{
   unsigned long filesize;
   unsigned char buff[4];
}x = {.filesize = file.size());
```